# System of Partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve numerically a system of 3 partial differential equations and I am facing a problem.
My functions are `f[x,t]`, `g[x,t]` and `h[x,t]` and are defined for `x`  values between  `S` and `R` (for some values of `R` and `S`).
The differential equations with the boundary conditions are the following:

```
eqnsNC= { D[f[x, t],t]== DM * D[f[x, t], x,x]-kf * f[x, t] * h[x, t]+kdis * g[x, t], D[h[x, t], t]==DL * D[h[x, t], x,x]-kf * f[x, t] *h[x, t]+kdis * g[x, t],D[g[x, t], t]==DML * D[g[x, t], x,x]+kf * f[x, t] * h[x, t]-kdis *g[x, t]}; bc={f^(1,0)[R,t]==g^(1,0)[R,t]==h^(1,0)[R,t]==0, f[x,0]==g[x,0]==h[x,0]==0, f[S,t]==MS * (1-Exp[-1000 t]), g[S,t]==(kf * LS* MS * (1-Exp[-1000 t]))/kdis, h[S,t]==LS * (1-Exp[-1000 t])};
```

With a bunch of constants

```
DM = 5*10^-6;   DL = 5*10^-6; DML = 5*10^-6; kf = 10^3; kdis = 63.8; MS = 0.25; LS = 0.2; 
R = 0.12; NN = 0.1; S = 0.05; tf = 10000;
```

Until there everything works and I can solve the system using the command

```
{fsol2, gsol2, hsol2} =  NDSolveValue[{eqnsNC, bc}, {f, g, h}, {x, S, R}, {t, 0, tf}]
```

However, for the real problem I need to add an additional constraint that states that the function `f[x,t]` is actually `0` on the region   `NN<x<R`,  for a value of `NN` such that `S<NN<R` and for all `t`.
The boundary condition df/fx =0 in R is therefore redundant but I cannot implement the above constraint.
I tried to change the boundary conditions by adding  `f[NN, t] == 0`  but I am running into errors when trying to get the numerical solutions such as

> NDSolveValue::bcedge: Boundary condition f[8,t]==0 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain. >>

How can I tell *Mathematica* to solve for `f` on the region `S<x<R` only and for `h` and `g` on the region `R<x<S`?
Or is it possible to define a given set of equations on a particular domain (for example in my case  for `S<x<NN` ) and another one for another region (`NN<x<R`)?

I would be very grateful for any advices you could think of !

Maud

Comment: please post the equations using correct mathematica syntax.

Comment: To follow up on the comment by @george2079, edit your code so that it is in `InputForm`.  For instance, `\[PartialD]f(x,t)/\[PartialD]t` should be `D[f[x, t], t]`.  It also could be displayed as `Derivative[0, 1][f][x, t]`.

Comment: And please also post the rest of the code. I.e There is an `NDSolve` message but no `NDSolve` command in your question.

Comment: Hello,  I am sorry for the wring syntax and I hope it is clearer now. Looking forward for your answers!